# Is there a way to hide data points with zero values in a pie chart when loading?

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

I am trying to build a pie chart and a timeline chart using echarts.js. My goal is to hide the data points that have zero values from my pie chart.

For instance, I do not want these 0's to appear: [image]

I just want to show the data points that have non-zero values, in this case, only the joy sentiment with number of tweets 3 and its percentage (100%).

This problem is two-fold:

1. I want to hide the data points with non-zero values when the chart load (the first time).
2. I want to hide the data points with non-zero values when I move the axisPointer.

I solved the 2).

```
myChart.on('updateAxisPointer', function (event) {
        const xAxisInfo = event.axesInfo[0];
        if (xAxisInfo) {
          const dimension = xAxisInfo.value + 1;
          myChart.setOption({
            series: {
              id: 'pie',
              label: {
                formatter: function(params) {
                  if (params.data[dimension] === 0) {
                    return '';
                  } else {
                    return params.name + ': ' + params.value[dimension] + ' (' + params.percent + '%)';
                  }
                }
              },
              encode: {
                value: dimension,
                tooltip: dimension
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
```

The logic of this code block is from the official documentation of the library, found in this example, [here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=dataset-link). The difference is that I thought the solution of hiding the data points of non zero values with the if block. And it works. When I move my mouse, and the axisPointer updates, I only see data points with non-zero values, with the pie chart correctly displaying them, like so:
[image]

However, when my chart loads the first time, I see everything, because I have the label formatter in this form in my option object:

```
label: {formatter: '{b}: {@Tue Jan 26, 10:00} ({d}%)'}
```

How can I solve this?

I should add that I am new in learning the echarts.js library, and I have not yet fully understood the above code block found in the given example. The library does not provide a complete documentation, nor it explains the given example. I am blind, searching in the dark here.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What prevents you from using the same formatter function for the second (initial) case?

Comment: @kikon I cannot use the same formatter function for the initial case, because I do not have access to the event parameter. The code given above is inside an event function handler.

The formatter for my initial case rests in the label property of my option object. I can use a callback function in that label, but I do not know how to access the same information that I accessed with the event parameter. 

That is essentially my question.

Comment: You can use the same formatter for the initial data, except for setting a fixed value for `dimension` - if your `@Tue Jan 26, 10:00` is the first date (the first index on x axis) then that corresponds to `xAxisInfo.value` being 0 and `dimension` being `1`. So just set `dimension = 1` for the initial formatter. Also, a simple condition would be (for both) `if(params.percent === 0)`.

Comment: @kikon I will! Thank you for your great help, it was really helpful and I think I understand the whole thing in echarts.js a bit more!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the complete solution you were seeking, but I did experiment with the example you provided in your question. You can visit the link I've shared below to get a better idea of what you're trying to achieve. Here's the code for your reference:

[Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=dataset-link&theme=dark&code=M4UwLgKglgtiD2BXMAKAZogdgYzFemABCgJSEDeAsAFCGHwAOeBhAvBTXXQDYgDmITABMAXBQC-AGk5cw8eNzwMxVWlzpgATlD4DNYgOQBDAB5RgB6WvXAAFvADuAYQJhBYMWiPdQMulL9CISMwI1APDmsuYCRNbBAxAG1A9USDBk14IURcS0IDACYABgBGArzC0oBmCuKSgBZa0oBWJpKANjaAdgMAXSt1VIMAWShuAGtCCBAjPKLJQiqugDoShYAOdeWuha6i1YXmquX6jebV_pSuNOGQ7FsjQgAZELc5w5KTw_O1wiPlqq7Y7rBbtLZdS5RIZOWwgECgQgubDwWYLeaEdoFZYFUEATmWzQWVXaX0I9XOOMWWOakMG1wMAHVvJhkIQAEKZByYKAgd6EdZY371T6UkogxbHXELer4kq9K7yqIBKImACCZmAKkIYAAngwEvlsCF-PBNDqDIRleoderzFq-NohABJYQgExiIqWgZcB1QUQUbWMQzNZoAUgtVuiIG08KSV1UdI0eoNBm4UEwvO9dOAMHkYFsYi0iBAWcGoBjwBeOqQYDZOsMnMsVzoIBgDAewDtAbQ8GwiE1-XLPIsXubhGAOpgACMFIZMARM2OYEZNOMAArwdMRciEMd0YKhONQxM73X6wzLkx5TBGOAX0wR0uJgNnlMwdPX29vj-WveEWnPuOk4ztwADKUAAF4Gok6JFP0u7Hv4T6jseCaJq-hhphmTaIeOubwPmhaaMWyF0EO8JVjWdYNo4OHPq27ZhF2O49n2A4GORI6RtmwGzvk87YaRhDLquG5blqf4HkYR6AVwp7JveV4LDed75Jej5_nQ8nnmpH7KV-F4_uIf4Ac-E7Tgo4FQUksHwWO3FcA5Wljhh-RYYuuE5nmBbasRJZjpxlHINR-SNkJDEdsxhCsf2hicRpnm8dwc4LnkS4ruum6YNuCGyVJMmyS-ClqQ--mqQY6koYVRU6RVemECp36YBGJlCWRSVWdBtkLPZyFOZEz6uam6YeWZ-GEb5JEBdGw5BbW9ahbR4VtpFA4sb2sWDjN8IJWZSUpYJuWJiJmXiQGkkhNJhDJLh6jaW-pUNQZJVXlVhX3YZzVlU1LW3f-bVARZYGQV1aJ2bh_X9WhdJDQwPJ0YmfqGHDo2JpoRhCFAm0GFURThkJ8TZdGSQGM0eO1GGfTLYxnZrX-MXsaA3BoAYvVjtwRhTiAyUDYBPaaMuYBuPo-TkFO4gqAAAnUBTiMQ5BCOIoYkKzEPhTgWQGtDiNuDAAByz3pJk2S5ADABu3jFoYMsI4N8iKFAyj5Db9lXMZUSKv4ADcMgwDqMIrmAywECgBiIAwB4gLawBiUTmh5BgODMEQKAgGb7hkNryKYMAYCEGqGouj2bCEGn7jLKY8JF_AMG9D7URQGgxAF-Y1eZ1c2e50EsCCJ2LDsC3wDV8sFvcMWhAANSECU9d0n7AeaEH4QAPJMPgmAoNrNjbXTf1I_kKO24mHNczzW-JvzgvC54WC4OvxAMCut7AO3f3qI3D9PzAwDLFJiSY3AHO69ehsFYOwIor9qrqE0OARAmgiAGAMLPKBctuYInPrJGBYA4FEEfujb-yxGqT3yIYYheDn4j0tiAf-PcgEEBAVPC0ocyFfx_vqOI7hiEGGVkgzSjk-Hu1kv1dQghkRCC1nw0eVtu6AL7pgAGGh7ZKDEAA3u68_yCMTJo9Q4gSDIP8DIXRyD54PEXssFea8Q6MGTnomgRigA)

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  option = {
    legend: {},
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'axis',
      showContent: false
    },
    dataset: {
      source: [
        ['product', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017'],
        ['Milk Tea', 0, 37.1, 88.7, 70.1, 53.4, 85.1],
        ['Matcha Latte', 0, 51.4, 55.1, 53.3, 73.8, 68.7],
        ['Cheese Cocoa', 0, 62.2, 69.5, 36.4, 45.2, 32.5],
        ['Walnut Brownie', 0, 82.1, 41.2, 18, 33.9, 49.1]
      ]
    },
    xAxis: { type: 'category' },
    yAxis: { gridIndex: 0 },
    grid: { top: '55%' },
    series: [
      {
        type: 'line',
        smooth: true,
        seriesLayoutBy: 'row',
        emphasis: { focus: 'series' },
        symbol: 'none',
        markPoint: { 
          data: [
            { type: 'max', name: 'max' },
            { type: 'min', name: 'min' }
          ],
          symbolSize: [0, 0], 
        },
      },
      {
        type: 'line',
        smooth: true,
        seriesLayoutBy: 'row',
        emphasis: { focus: 'series' },
        symbol: 'none',
        markPoint: { 
          data: [
            { type: 'max', name: 'max' },
            { type: 'min', name: 'min' }
          ],
          symbolSize: [0, 0], 
        },
      },
      {
        type: 'line',
        smooth: true,
        seriesLayoutBy: 'row',
        emphasis: { focus: 'series' },
        symbol: 'none', 
        markPoint: { 
          data: [
            { type: 'max', name: 'max' },
            { type: 'min', name: 'min' }
          ],
          symbolSize: [0, 0], 
        },
      },
      {
        type: 'line',
        smooth: true,
        seriesLayoutBy: 'row',
        emphasis: { focus: 'series' },
        symbol: 'none', 
        markPoint: { 
          data: [
            { type: 'max', name: 'max' },
            { type: 'min', name: 'min' }
          ],
          symbolSize: [0, 0], 
        },
      },
      {
        type: 'pie',
        id: 'pie',
        radius: '30%',
        center: ['50%', '25%'],
        emphasis: {
          focus: 'self'
        },
        label: {
          formatter: '{b}: {@2012} ({d}%)'
        },
        encode: {
          itemName: 'product',
          value: '2012',
          tooltip: '2012'
        }
      }
    ]
  };
  myChart.on('updateAxisPointer', function (event) {
    const xAxisInfo = event.axesInfo[0];
    if (xAxisInfo) {
      const dimension = xAxisInfo.value + 1;
      myChart.setOption({
        series: {
          id: 'pie',
          label: {
            formatter: function (params) {
              if (params.data[dimension] === 0) {
                return '';
              } else {
                return params.name + ': ' + params.value[dimension] + ' (' + params.percent + '%)';
              }
            }
          },
          encode: {
            value: dimension,
            tooltip: dimension
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
  myChart.setOption(option);
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help at all as markPoints and symbolSize have nothing to do with what I aim to solve, from my understanding.